# How to maintain the order of rows in the data frame using Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to maintain the order of the rows in the data frame in Pyspark. Is there any way to achieve this for this function here we have the row ID which will give numbering to each row. Currently, the below function results in the rearrangement of the row in the data frame.

```py
def createRowIdColumn( new_column, position, start_value):
    row_count = df.count()
    row_ids = spark.range(int(start_value), int(start_value) + row_count, 1).toDF(new_column)
    window = Window.orderBy(lit(1))
    df_row_ids = row_ids.withColumn("row_num", row_number().over(window) - 1)
    df_with_row_num = df.withColumn("row_num", row_number().over(window) - 1)

    if position == "Last Column":
        result = df_with_row_num.join(df_row_ids, on="row_num").drop("row_num")
    else:
        result = df_row_ids.join(df_with_row_num, on="row_num").drop("row_num")
       
    return result.orderBy(new_column)
```

Please let me know the solution if we can achieve this requirement.

Comment: you could order by the row ID itself within the window. seems it is sequential.

Comment: if your data resides in multiple files and then they will be read in a distributed manner so there is no guarantee of order. But if you care to assign a temporary rowId after reading in the data and do operations on that rowId then `monotonically_increasing_id` can do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df3=df3.withColumn('row',row_number().over(Window.partitionBy().orderBy(monotonically_increasing_id())))
```